# Calculating input impedance of 3 port network

Tags: network

I am trying to derive a expression for calculating the input impedance of a 3 port network to use as direct calculating code and avoid SPICE/simulator solving of the same.

I am able to solve the input impedance of a 2 port system  with a load, \$Z_{load}\$, connected to port 2. The impedance looking into port 1 would be (by solving basic 2 port theory):

$$
Z_{in} = Z_{11} - \frac{Z_{21}Z_{12}}{Z_{22}+Z_{load}}
$$

If I have a 3 port network with 2 ports connected to different loads, \$Z_{load1}\$ and \$Z_{load2}\$, how can I generate an expression for \$Z_{in}\$ looking in from port 1 starting from only the Z-matrix, \$Z_{load1}\$ and \$Z_{load2}\$?

Comment: Can you use LaTex to type in your equation? It looks better.

Comment: Didn't you think it relevant to actually show the circuit of your 3 port network?

Comment: @Andyaka I believe he's referring to the 3-port version of a generic [two-port network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-port_network) instead of a specific circuit.

Comment: @Andyaka
Im sorry if my question wasnt too clear, but as Sven mentioned, it is for a generic network

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3-port can be described in 3 equations, using

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
V_1 \\
V_2 \\
V_3
\end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix}
Z_{11} & Z_{12} & Z_{13} \\
Z_{21} & Z_{22} & Z_{23} \\
Z_{31} & Z_{32} & Z_{33} \end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}
I_1 \\
I_2 \\
I_3\end{matrix}\right)$$

I will now load ports 1 and 2, while using port 3 as the input. Adding two loads adds two new equations

$$\begin{align}
V_1 &= -Z_{L1}\cdot I_1 \\
V_2 &= -Z_{L2}\cdot I_2
\end{align}$$

This can be inserted into the matrix notation:

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
Z_{11} & Z_{12} & Z_{13} \\
Z_{21} & Z_{22} & Z_{23} \\
Z_{31} & Z_{32} & Z_{33} \end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}
I_1 \\
I_2 \\
I_3\end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix}
-Z_{L1}\cdot I_1 \\
-Z_{L2}\cdot I_2 \\
V_3
\end{matrix}\right)$$

Which is the same as

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
Z_{11} + Z_{L1} & Z_{12} & Z_{13} \\
Z_{21} & Z_{22} + Z_{L2} & Z_{23} \\
Z_{31} & Z_{32} & Z_{33} \end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}
I_1 \\
I_2 \\
I_3\end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix}
0 \\
0 \\
V_3
\end{matrix}\right)$$

Since we want to solve for \$Z_{in} = \frac{V_3}{I_3}\$, we can use Cramer's rule to find

$$
I_3 = \frac{\left|\begin{matrix}
Z_{11} + Z_{L1} & Z_{12} & 0 \\
Z_{21} & Z_{22} + Z_{L_2} & 0 \\
Z_{31} & Z_{32} & V_3
\end{matrix}\right|}{\left|\begin{matrix}
Z_{11} + Z_{L1} & Z_{12} & Z_{13} \\
Z_{21} & Z_{22} + Z_{L2} & Z_{23} \\
Z_{31} & Z_{32} & Z_{33} \end{matrix}\right|}\
$$

Or also

$$
Z_{in} = \frac{V_3}{I_3} = \frac{\left|\begin{matrix}
Z_{11} + Z_{L1} & Z_{12} & Z_{13} \\
Z_{21} & Z_{22} + Z_{L2} & Z_{23} \\
Z_{31} & Z_{32} & Z_{33} \end{matrix}\right|}{\left|\begin{matrix}
Z_{11} + Z_{L1} & Z_{12} & 0 \\
Z_{21} & Z_{22} + Z_{L_2} & 0 \\
Z_{31} & Z_{32} & 1
\end{matrix}\right|}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the very clear derivation of the expression.
Which position of the resultant 3x3 matrix generated would be used as the Zin term to be plotted?

I tried implementing this expression in Python( taking inverse of the denominator matrix and multipying with numerator array to generate a 3x3 matrix) but could not match the result with simulator output ( sorry but unable to reproduce code due to company restrictions)

Comment: [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule) involves calculating determinants, ie. scalars. The result is not a matrix. \$|A| = det(A)\$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Really appreciate your help in understanding this complex problem