# 3 port matching of a directional coupler

Tags: impedance-matching

My goal is to apply resistive matching (L-pads/attenuators) to the ports of a Mini-Circuits ADC-10-4 directional coupler. I have a 3x3 impedance matrix derived from the available 3 port S-parameters. Within the context of the solution provided by Sven B:

[Calculating input impedance of 3 port network](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/405078/calculating-input-impedance-of-3-port-network/405118#405118)

can  "Z11 + Re(Z11)" and "Z22 + Re(Z22)" be substituted for "Z11 + ZL1" and "Z22 + ZL2," respectively, to obtain an expression for Zin under a matched condition and could this expression be adapted to provide a system of 3 equations, 3 unknowns to solve for matching load impedances ZL1, ZL2, and ZL3?

Comment: A diagram showing the kind of matching network you want to design would probably make your question more clear. Also, the ADC-10-4 is spec'ed with better than 10 dB return loss on all ports over all operating frequencies. Why do you think a matching network is needed?

Comment: The system I am building is for electron resonance studies at a surface that is part of a transmission line. At higher frequencies, standing waves could be problematic with respect to field uniformity over the working area, so I am willing to sacrifice efficiency/power in the signal chain to match to 50ohm cable or other components using simple resistive L-pads or pi attenuators (series and shunt combinations of resistors). I am generally trying to maintain a return loss of better than 30dB.

Comment: As the coupler is already good to 10dB per port, then a 10dB pad on a port will give you S11 of better than 30dB. SMA pads can be purchased with excellent match to very high frequencies at a reasonable price. If you bodge it together with 'series and shunt combinations of resistors' then you will have a difficult assembly and measurement problem.

Comment: @Neil_UK, Actual performance may be better, but if I check 3 or 4 high quality vendors I don't see any with  specified VSWR better than 1.15, giving return loss of -23 dB.

Comment: I am aware of the difficulties of SMT assembly, as I have worked on assembly processes for microwave integrated circuits used in missile and satellite programs (e.g., die attach of bare GaAsFETs). I already have a variety of SMA directional couplers, amplifiers, and attenuators, but as I have stated, I want to match to the ADC-10-4, which is a surface mount device, and I will  be matching it to devices that are not 50ohms. I appreciate the comments, but my question is directed to mathematics and the physical nature of the matching elements is not really relevant to the question.

Comment: Put that the devices around the ADC-10-4 will be non-50ohms in your OP. The way you've written it, it sounds like you want to trim up the coupler match to a better 50 ohms. What you're actually doing is matching your non-50ohm devices into a 50 ohm system. That's why we're all missing your point. What is the frequency range? What is the present measured S11 of your devices? What is the present measured S11 of your coupler?

Comment: The ADC-10-4 may or may not see 50 ohms. For example, at 1000MHz, the coupler  will connect the output of a PHA-13HLN SOT-89 amplifier (Zout = 23.9 + 3.1j) to a tunable matching circuit for the gate of a power LDMOSFET (Zin = .31 - 2.3j). The coupled port may be connected to an SMA edge connector or an SMD RF power detector of indeterminate impedance. I am not characterizing surface mount devices.  I use the manufacturer's S-parameters  with [https://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedias/s-parameter-utilities-spreadsheet] and my own VBA macros for 2-port resistive and reactive matching.